# Error al instalar firebase-tools a Angular

Tags: firebase, npm

Muy buenas.. estuve intentando instalar firebase-tools a Angular para hacer deploy de un proyecto...
Cuando utilizo el comando `npm install -g firebase-tools` me devuelve este error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)  
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 701 packages, and audited 702 packages in 23s

46 packages are looking for funding
 run `npm fund` for details

1 moderate severity vulnerability

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

**Edit**: acá se puede observar los WARN que me tira al intentar instalar las firebase-tools, pero al intentar iniciar o loguearme en firebase me aparece este error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
 throw err;
 ^
Error: Cannot find module 'p-limit'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\database\import.js
- C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\commands\database-import.js
- C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\commands\index.js
- C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\database\import.js:8:19)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\commands\database-import.js:8:18)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [
   'C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\database\\import.js',
   'C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\commands\\database-import.js',
   'C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\commands\\index.js',
   'C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\index.js',
   'C:\\Users\\Brian\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\lib\\bin\\firebase.js'
 ]
}
```

¿hay un modo de instalar esas librerías faltantes de manera manual o hacer algo para solucionar eso?

Comment: A qué error te refieres? Ahí hay 4 warnings sobre las dependencias y una indicación de una vulnerabilidad conocida en una de ellas. No veo errores.

Comment: ahí edite la publicación con el código de error que me aparece al intentar iniciar/loguearme en firebase

Answer (score 0):

Pues mira que [le pegaste a un bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5619) del módulo. De los de verdad verdadera.

Mientras publican una versión arreglada, prueba con una versión anterior, algo como

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@11.16.1
```